# Best way to enable user to have custom profile - like about.me profile

Tags: jquery, css, symfony

I'm working on a website with Symfony2. Every user has a profile page, which can be viewed by visitors. I want that a user can change some styles like background, colors, fonts, etc - like the way how the website about.me did this. My question is how to do that right?

Changing styles like background images on the fly with javascript and jquery thats fine. But how should the changes handled afterwords? Do I have to save the changes in the database? Should I create a custom user css file? How does a page like about.me does this? Is there anything else I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it started: you have to provide a control panel where the user can set various fields like

- background image
- font-family
- whatever

This values have to be save to a database and linked to the user with a one-to-one relation like

```
<entity name="My\MainBundle\Entity\User" table="user">
    <one-to-one field="page_settings" target-entity="PublicPageSettings" inversed-by="user"/>
</entity>

<entity name="My\MainBundle\Entity\PublicPageSettings" table="page_settings">
    <one-to-one field="user" target-entity="User" mapped-by="page_settings"/>
    <field name="fontFamily" column="font_family" type="string"/>
</entity>
```

Read on: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional

Upon that you can render the user's public page based on his custom settings.

Comment: Thanks this sounds good and actually easy. I was thinking too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a solution you can use HTML5 localstorage feature. You can set the values in javascript like :-

```
        localStorage.bgcolor= "red";
        localStorage.fontcolor = "white";
        localStorage.font-family = "Verdana";
```

And this values will be saved on the browser for lifetime. you can retrieve these values next time the user visits the web page.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The settings have to persisted somewhere on a server and not in the browser.